# WordPress Get All Posts With Specific Taxonomy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a custom PHP script that adds posts to WordPress and allows you to view/modify posts.

The WordPress Theme I'm using has specific `post_type`, and specific variables to that type.

I can add posts without any issues, but I'm having a difficult time trying to query all posts with the specific `tax_input` value.

Here is the code that adds posts:

```
include('../wp-config.php'); //Get WordPress Config
$new_listing = array(
    'post_title'    => $listing_title,
    'post_name'     => str_replace('-', ' ', $listing_title),
    'post_content'  => $listing_description,
    'tax_input'     => array('property-status' => $listing_phase),
    //$listing_phase is the `term_id` number from what I see in the database
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'property',
    'post_author'   => 1
);
$listing_id = wp_insert_post($new_listing); //Insert the post into the database
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_banner_sub_title', $listing_subtitle);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_address', $listing_address);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_location', $listing_address_lat.','.$listing_address_lng);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_size', $listing_sqare_foot);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_size_postfix', 'Sq Ft');
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms', $listing_bedrooms);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms', $listing_bathrooms);
add_post_meta($listing_id, 'REAL_HOMES_property_garage', $listing_garage);
```

What do I need to do to get posts with the same `tax_input` value?

The below code gets all the `properties` but with all `property-status` values, I want to show only a certain `properties` with certain `property-status` values:

```
$postArgs = array('posts_per_page' => 25, 'post_type' => 'property');
$getListings = get_posts($postArgs);
foreach($getListings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
    <a href="<?=the_permalink()?>" class="deploy-toggle-1"><?=the_title()?></a>
    <div class="content"><p><?=the_content()?></p></div>
<?
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Is add_post_meta() just a thing that we're supposed to know about?

Comment: @Strawberry Well it *IS* a WordPress built in function, I did not create it! Maybe you should do research before replying!! http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Comment: Yes. You're probably right.

Comment: what is in the `$listing_phase` ??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue once I found the Wordpress documentation for taxonomies.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

The working code:

```
$postArgs = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 25,
            'post_type'     => 'property',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property-status', //Tax_Input
                    'field' => 'term_id', //Or Slug
                    'terms' => '48' //Term ID or Slug Name
                )
            )
        );
$getListings = get_posts($postArgs);
foreach($getListings as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
     <a>" class="deploy-toggle-1"><?=the_title()?></a>
     <div class="content"><p><?=the_content()?></p></div>
<?
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It is not all post from tax, it is all post from term